# Need Help in Join Query

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables:

tbl_Invoice

[image: Invoice]

tbl_payment

[image: Payment]

When I pass client_Id = `5` then the Desired Output should be:

```
PSUM        IPRICE          Amt_Type
----------- -------------- ----------------
100.00      100.00         USD
  0.00      1000.00        GBP
```

Where

`PSUM` is Sum of total Payments

`IPRICE` is Sum of total Price of Invoices

What I have tried is:

```
Select SUM(P.Amt) as PSUM, SUM(I.Total_price) as IPRICE, I.Amt_Type  from
[tbl_payment] P left join [tbl_Invoice] I on P.invoice_Id = I.invoice_Id
    WHERE P.client_id = @Client_Id and I.client_id = @Client_Id
    group by I.Amt_Type
```

Comment: What is the logic for that data?  What are the `PSUM` and `IPRICE` fields in your source tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following appears to be working:

```
declare @client_id int = 5

select 
  IsNull(sum(p.amt), 0) PSUM,
  IsNull(sum(i.total_price), 0) IPRICE,
  i.amt_type
from tbl_invoice i
left join tbl_payment p
  on i.invoice_id = p.invoice_id
  and i.client_id = p.client_id
where i.client_id = @client_id
group by i.amt_type, i.invoice_id
order by i.invoice_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7d37/8)

Result:

```
| PSUM | IPRICE | AMT_TYPE |
----------------------------
|  100 |    100 |      USD |
|    0 |   1000 |      GBP |
```